# What is the point of upgrading my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've just bought the first available house and I've spent all my money on it. Great, now I have a place to store my dragon bones until I become Mr. Smith (oh dear what a pun), but what's the point in upgrading the furnishings and such?

- Is it just to add more storage space? Isn't every chest infinite size?
- Is it just to add alchemy stations, etc? Aren't these readily and freely available elsewhere?
- Is it just to look nicer? Isn't that just purely vanity and a waste of gold?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're correct on all three questions.  I think one point is that you get all of that stuff in the same place, and with multiple chests you can organize stuff more.  For example, I have a smithing cabinet and an equipment chest.  Also, your house is usually more conveniently located than wherever the alchemy lab and enchanting table happen to be in a given city.

The other thing you get is some weapon racks (2 in the house in Whiterun) and armor stands (0 in Whiterun, unfortunately).  These let you display weapons and armor, which is a nice little point of customization.  I have the [Sanguine Rose](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sanguine_Rose) sitting in mine, and it looks pretty neat.

So no, you don't *really* get anything new beyond the first container (which is valuable because your stuff won't grow legs while it's in there).  So what are the upgrades for?  Completionists, mostly.  I might not get every house, but I plan to fully upgrade the ones I do, because they look nice.  (Also, some of the upgrades to later houses get you, for example, a cabinet full of good potions, IIRC.)  The house upgrades are what an MMO player might call a "gold sink", and after all you will end up with quite a bit of it.

Comment: Shame it doesn't provide some sort of actual benefit - I think I'll hold off on the upgrades until I've got more gold than I need. As I've just spent it all I now have about 30 gold :)

Comment: Yeah, you'll eventually get to the point where you have more gold than you know what to do with, especially if you do alchemy and/or pickpocketing.  Then you'll know what to do with it!

Comment: why alchemy? making and selling potions? I've been dabbling around with it but nothing major. I do compulsively pick every flower I find in the wild though! If I can make lots of gold I'll put some time into it.

Comment: I haven't done any math or whatever, but you can make a lot of money from alchemy over time.  There's a site somewhere that will tell you the most expensive potions you can make out of whatever you have around.  But since you don't generally need any potions besides health and magicka, the rest that you make and sell are pure profit.

Comment: @andronikus If you can stumble across that site again, please link?  I will say that I'm level 19 right now, and haven't really made any concerted efforts to build wealth - and I've got 10k sitting in my chest in Whiterun, and about 5k on my person, which I have no plans for.

Comment: Done: http://www.endoftheweb.se/skyrim/.  Also http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemy_Tips#Making_Money has some good tips.